# Formato de data errado no xamarin forms, como resolver?

Tags: datetime, xamarin-forms

Na minha aplicação mobile eu tenho uma parte que recupero a data e hora local, portanto a data esta trazendo primeiro o mês, depois o dia e por ultimo ano, como mudar isso, aqui está o meu código:

***No meu arquivo de layout:***

```
<Label Text="Data" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
<Label Text="{Binding DataAtual}"/>
```

***Aqui a classe criada para a parte lógica:***

```
public class DataHora : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private DateTime _dataAtual;
    public DateTime DataAtual
    {
        set
        {
            if (_dataAtual == value)
                return;

            _dataAtual = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(DataAtual)));
        }
        get
        {
            return _dataAtual;
        }
    }

    public DataHora()
    {
        DataAtual = DateTime.Now;

        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
        {
            DataAtual = DateTime.Now;
            return true;
        });
    }
}
```

***E aqui no meu arquivo mainpage:***

```
BindingContext = new DataHora();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Binding oferece suporte para definição do formato de string que você quer apresentar.

Basta mudar no seu XAML o Binding do label para o seguinte:

```
<Label Text="{Binding DataAtual, StringFormat='{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}'}"/>
```

Se você só faz o Binding cru, o comportamento padrão é um `ToString()` no objeto, e nesse caso, certamente ele está seguindo o formato da data definido na cultura do seu emulador, muito provavelmente `en-US`;

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado! Apenas acrescentei também hh:mm:ss e ficou filé.